# unable to pass data to c# code using AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to pass some specific data to C# code-behind using AJAX code, but couldn't managed to accomplish it. I've tried using plain text data type and json format, but neither of them are working for me.

The following error occurred when I tried to send the data using json method:

> Internal Server Error

when using text method, there is no error appear and the code comes through the `success` function, but the actually the data is never sent to the method of the code-behind class

And this is the ajax code using json format:

```
function searchClicked(sCriterion) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "TokenRegistration.aspx/GetSearchCritetrion",
    data: "{creiterion : " + sCriterion + " }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert("We returned: " + result);
    }
});
```

}

And this is the ajax code using the text format:

```
function searchClicked(sCriterion) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "TokenRegistration.aspx/GetSearchCritetrion",
        data: sCriterion,
        contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text",
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("We returned: " + result);
        }
    });
}
```

Also here is the my code-behind method that the data should be sent to:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void GetSearchCritetrion(object selectedItem)
{
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var data = json.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>[]>(selectedItem.ToString());
}
```

I've used the exact same ajax code in another project and it works perfectly, but here i'm not getting where the error is, so any suggestions please?

Comment: does the control reach `GetSearchCritetrion()` action method ?

Comment: no dear it doesn't reach that method, @Kumar_Vikas

Comment: why do you need an `object selectedItem`? can you pass a SelectedItem instead? or string or a class?

Comment: it should be static method used with .aspx.cs file

Comment: @JericCruz i already changed it to `string`, but still getting the same error

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash also i changed the method to static

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash yes i changed it to string but sorry what do u mean by put ajax code in jquery loaded portion?

Comment: Put you javascript code inside $(function(){   ..}) In this portion

Comment: oh ok, already this is done but still facing the exact problem

Comment: Update jQuery version ,,plz use latest jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code like this

.aspx

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            function searchClicked(sCriterion) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetSearchCritetrion",
                    data: "{creiterion : " + sCriterion + " }",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("We returned: " + result);
                    }
                });
            }

            searchClicked("1");


        });

        </script>
```

and .cs file

```
[WebMethod]
    public static String GetSearchCritetrion(String creiterion)
    {
        return "ok";
    }
```

and App_Start

```
 public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
            settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;//Its may cause the error
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks dear, but in my project i don't have file called: App_Start, i changed the rest as u mentioned, but still getting the same error

Comment: Did you cahnge the parameter of .aspx.cs file to string and put ajax code in jquery loaded portion..this works fine in my machine.

Comment: and please notice that when I put my code inside the jquery loaded portion, the code is no longer go through these functions.

Answer (score 0):

in your client side:

```
function searchClicked(sCriterion) {
    //display the parameter
    console.log(sCriterion);

    if(sCriterion != "" || sCriterion != null)
    {
        var param= {
            "selectedItem" : sCriterion 
         };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TokenRegistration.aspx/GetSearchCritetrion",
            data: param,
            success: function(result) {
              alert("We returned: " + result);
             },
             error: function(error){
                 console.log(error);
             }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("No values!!");
    }
}
```

server side:

```
[WebMethod]
public void GetSearchCritetrion(string selectedItem)
{
    //add a breakpoint here....

}
```